# MySql ALTER TABLE on Production Databases - Any Issues?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have about 100 databases (all the same structure, just on different servers) with approx a dozen tables each. Most tables are small (lets say 100MB or less). There are occasional edge-cases where a table may be large (lets say 4GB+).

I need to run a series of ALTER TABLE commands on just about every table in each database. Mainly adding some rows to the structure, but a few changes like change a row from a varchar to tinytext (or vice versa). Also adding a few new indexes (but indexing new rows, not existing ones, so assuming that isn't a big deal).

I am wondering how safe this is to do, and if there are any best practices to this process.

First, is there any chance I may corrupt or delete data in the tables. I suspect no, but need to be certain.

Second, I presume for the larger tables (4GB+), this may be a several-minutes to several-hours process?

Anything and everything I should know about performing ALTER TABLE commands on a production database I am interested in learning.

If its of any value knowing, I am planning on issuing commands via PHPMYADMIN for the most part.

Thanks -

Comment: Nice question, would be nice to see the answer to this - my initial suspicion is that it wouldn't take too long as I don't think MySQL has to edit every row if you're altering a table - not certain though, look forward to more educated minds throwing themselves at this one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off before applying any changers, make backups.  Two ways you can do it:  `mysqldump` everything or you can copy your mysql data folder.

Secondly, you may want to use `mysql` from the command line.  PHPMyAdmin will probably time out.  Most PHP server has timeout less than 10 minutes.  Or you accidently close the browser.

Comment: backing up ~100 databases with table sizes between 100MB and 4GB+ must be worth another question :-)

Comment: any possible issues regarding to locked rows?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

1. You can do fail-over the apps.(make sure no connections on all dbs) .
2. You can create indexes by using "create index statements" .don't use alter table add index statements.
3. Do these all using script like(keep all these statements in a file and run from source).
4. Looks like table sizes are very small so it wont create any headache.